# row wise duplicate data need to be eliminated(Rowspan) using Django Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

As i have a dictionary in python. Dictionary values look like.

```
d= {'Report.thpl Team =FULL':{'cdp.c': 899, '_arp_fusen.c': 34, 'discovery.c': 34, 'subnet.c': 4},
 'P1.thpl Team = Over': {'discovery.c': 34, 'file23.c': 4, 'cdp/cdp.c': 937, '_fusen.c': 83},
 'P1_Report1.thpl': {'arp_fusen.c': 83, 'disynet.c': 34, 'routes.c': 2, 'routing.c': 937}}
```

**My table looks this**

```
|test                   | file_name          |coverage   |
**********************************************************
|Report.thpl Team =FULL | cdp.c              | 899       |
|Report.thpl Team =FULL | _arp_fusen.c       | 34        |
|Report.thpl Team =FULL | Discovery.c        | 34        |
|Report.thpl Team =FULL | subnet.c           | 4         |
|P1.thpl Team = Over    | discovery.c        | 34        |
|P1.thpl Team = Over    | file23.c           |  4        |
|P1.thpl Team = Over    | cdp/cdp.c          | 937       |
|P1.thpl Team = Over    | _fusen.c           | 83        |
|P1_Report1.thpl        | arp_fusen.c        | 83        |
|P1_Report1.thpl        | disynet.c          | 34        |
|P1_Report1.thpl        | routes.c           | 2         |
|P1_Report1.thpl        | routing.c          | 937       |
***********************************************************
```

**code in article.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:80%;" >
        <tr style="color:white;">
            <th>Test Case</th>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Coverage</th>
        </tr>
       {% for key, value in d.items %}
        <tr>
            {% for k,v in value.items %}
             {% if forloop.parentloop.first %}
            <td rowspan="{{ key|length }}">{{ key }}</td>
            {% endif %}
            <td>{{ k }}</td>
           <td>{{ v }}</td>

             {% endfor %}

        </tr>
            {% endfor %}

         {% endif %}
    </table>
```

But i am getting row wise output using above code. as i need output in below format. Please do help me.

```
|test                   | file_name          |coverage   |
**********************************************************
|Report.thpl Team =FULL | cdp.c              | 899       |
|                       | _arp_fusen.c       | 34        |
|                       | Discovery.c        | 34        |
|                       | subnet.c           | 4         |
|P1.thpl Team = Over    | discovery.c        | 34        |
|                       | file23.c           |  4        |
|                       | cdp/cdp.c          | 937       |
|                       | _fusen.c           | 83        |
|P1_Report1.thpl        | arp_fusen.c        | 83        |
|                       | disynet.c          | 34        |
|                       | routes.c           | 2         |
|                       | routing.c          | 937       |
***********************************************************
```

As i need test attribute not to repeat and it should be distinct.Please do help me out.

Comment: d is not a valid python dict..

Comment: i just named dictionary variable as d

Comment: is that there shouldn't be a colon after `'Report.thpl Team =FULL'` ?

Comment: sorry while editing i deleted colon .that is an valid dictionary please do give solution for displaying based on my needs

Answer (score 1):

instead of plain `{{ key }}`
you can try :

```
<td rowspan="{{ key|length }}">
    {% if forloop.first %}
        {{ key }}
     {% endif %}
</td>
```

OR

```
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width:80%;" >
            <tr style="color:white;">
                <th>Test Case</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Coverage</th>
            </tr>
           {% for key, value in d.items %}
             {% for k,v in value.items %}
               <tr>
                 <td> 
                    {% if forloop.parentloop.first %}
                      {{ key }}
                    {% endif %}
                 </td>
                 <td>{{ k }}</td>
                 <td>{{ v }}</td>
               </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}

        </table>
```

Comment: how to sort the dict value.items based on 'v' in second for loop.Please do help me out.

Comment: {% for k,v in value.items|sort %}

Comment: based on value of 'v' i need to sort

Comment: better if you send sorted values from backend itself

Comment: i'm trying to do using so=sorted(d.iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1)) but its not working i need to sort based on coverage on table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165960/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-vinay).